# Storm on Earth vs. storm on Jupiter?

Tags: earth, jupiter, cyclones

Why is the storm on Jupiter much stronger than storms on Earth and why don't the storms on Earth get as big as Jupiter's great red spot

Answer (score 2):

Basically because Jupiter is a gas giant and thousands of times more massive than the Earth. Everything on Jupiter is on a gigantic scale. The Great Red Spot for instance could accommodate several Earths, so that explains why you couldn't have a storm on Earth which came anywhere near that size. As well as heat from the sun, which is what drives the weather on Earth, Jupiter has a massive internal source of heat.

Comment: I can't see why this was voted down.

Comment: There are other considerations as well: Jupiter's rapid rotation (once per 10 hours or so) provided additional energy, while the lack of a solid surface removes a number of effects which tend to damp down storms on Earth after at most a few weeks.

Comment: @StephenG It's a matter of principle with Astronomy Stack users to vote me down, because they know I'm not one of them and have a completely different mind set (thank God!!). The downvoting system is wide open to abuse, which is why I never use it.

Comment: @SteveLinton I don't know if you're intending these as reasons to downvote, but in case you are I'll state that I don't think that would be sufficient grounds to downvote.  Regardless it might be more useful to Astronomy SE in general if you could develop a proper answer explaining the relative importance of these factors.  It's not an area I have much detailed knowledge of myself.

Comment: @MichaelWalsby I have voted down some of your answers myself and I think many of your answers, while well intentioned, have not been of a good standard.  Nonethless this answer seems appropriate to the question to me.

Comment: Michael, I downvote (and upvote) based on the usefulness of an answer. Many of your answers are either wrong, or aren't useful because they're personal opinion rather than providing evidence-based science, and I therefore DV them. Occasionally you post a good answer and I upvote it. This one (IMHO) doesn't deserve a vote either way: it's not wrong, but it doesn't include key details such as the ones @SteveLinton [mentions](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/33357/storm-on-earth-vs-storm-on-jupiter#comment63039_33358).

Comment: That still doesn't alter the fact that the downvoting system is wide open to abuse. Several site mandarins have in effect told me that: they couldn't understand why I was getting so many downvotes for a good answer..